# FTP upload of files - how to determine file upload has been completed on the server

Tags: c#, ftp

I need to write a utility in C#. The utility has to invoke a web-service once a file has been uploaded via FTP. The files are text files (so they dont have an end-of-file marker and they can be pretty big).

The ftp server is the built in ftp server within Windows.

My question is: How do I determine whether the file upload has been completed? (so that I can call the web-service and tell it about the file?) If I dont wait to find out the file has been uploaded, then I might end up notifying the web-service prematurely (especially for really large files)

Comment: how do you upload the files on the FTP server? Via C#? show some code please

Comment: Do you have any control over the FTP process

Comment: Is this utility running on the server, or on the client that's doing the upload?

Answer (score 0):

Have your process upload the file to a temporary directory and execute a move command to the destination directory.

This way you know any files in your destination directory are complete.